# What Gaussian process covariance function captures an affine mean?

Tags: self-study, matlab, gaussian-process

In the [documentation for GPML](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/), the author trained a GP with an affine mean function and isotropic squared exponential covariance function. Then there is an exercise to the reader:

> Try training a GP where the affine part of the function is captured by the covariance function instead of the mean function. That is, use a GP with no explicit mean function, but further additive contributions to the covariance.

My question is: **How do I design the covariance function in order to capture affine mean?**